# How Change FontFamily Of A TextBox In A Windows Application RunTime(Code Behind)

Tags: c#, readonly, windows, font-family

How can i change the FontFamily of a TextBox in a windows application runtime(code behind)?
why the code below has error :

```
txtSubjectIn_Spammer_Send.Font.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

and it's error is :

> Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.FontFamily' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Font oldFont = txtSubjectIn_Spammer_Send.Font;
txtSubjectIn_Spammer_Send.Font = new Font("Arial", oldFont.Size, oldFont.Style);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the `FontFamily`, which is derived from `Font`, but you *can* change the `Font`, like so:

```
txtSubjectIn_Spammer_Send.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this will work out, you are actually really close:

```
txtSubjectIn_Spammer_Send.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
```